# Intercept Command+key with IMKit (or similar)

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, appkit, input-method-kit

I was looking to intercept Command key combinations and thought that `IMKit` would be a good choice. By extending `IMKInputController` I can intercept most keys but it seems to ignore modified ones.

I've tried overriding

```
-(BOOL)inputText:(NSString*)string client:(id)sender;
```

and (alternatively)

```
-(BOOL)inputText:(NSString*)string 
             key:(NSInteger)keyCode 
       modifiers:(NSUInteger)flags 
          client:(id)sender;
```

but no luck; the methods just plain aren't called when the modifiers are applied. To be more specific the `command` and `alt` key don't get caught by the methods above. Simple modifiers like `shift` and `ctrl` work (and the modifier `flags` variable is set in the second method). Fire up Apple's sample application [NumberInput](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/NumberInput_IMKit_Sample/Introduction/Intro.html) to see for yourself.

Any suggestions? Am I on totally the wrong track?

Comment: what happens, they aren't called? "No luck" is a little vague...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer:

> Use `handleEvent:client:` and listen to the `NSFlagsChanged` event.

---

`IMKInputController` implements the [IMKServerInput Protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/IMKServerInput_Additions/Reference/IMKServerInput.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006161-CH3-743333), which provides three alternatives to handle an event.

1. Key binding - using `inputText:client:` and `didCommandBySelector:client:`
2. Text data only - using `inputText:key:modifiers:client:`
3. Handle all events - using `handleEvent:client:`

Seems like you've only tried the top two. You can achieve the goal with the third option.

Try the following:

1. override `recognizedEvents:` (from [IMKStateSetting Protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/IMKStateSetting_Protocol/Reference/IMKStateSetting_Ref.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006159-CH3-DontLinkElementID_2))

   ```
   - (NSUInteger)recognizedEvents:(id)sender
   {
       return NSKeyDownMask | NSFlagsChangedMask;
   }
   ```
2. and use `handleEvent:client:`

   ```
   -(BOOL)handleEvent:(NSEvent*)event client:(id)sender
   {
       NSLog(@"handling event: %@", event);
       return false;
   }
   ```

You can see the printout on every keydown and keyup of the modifiers in Console, including `command` and `alt`.

Comment: Testing this, setting `NSKeyUpMask` in `recognizedEvents:` still does not catch `NSKeyUp` type events. Thought that would be the solution to this issue, but apparently not: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23620864/imkit-to-catch-nskeyup-event