# IMKit to catch NSKeyup event

Tags: cocoa, events, input-method-kit

As an experiment, I am trying to achieve the following:

- Let spacebar work as a modifier key - like the Shift key - where holding the spacebar key down and typing keys print different letters. Releasing the spacebar would set the state back to normal, and just pressing it behaves like a normal space key.

I was thinking of handling the keydown and keyup event, but apparently `handleEvent:client:` in [IMKServerInput Protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/IMKServerInput_Additions/Reference/IMKServerInput.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006161-CH3-SW4) seems to only catch key down and mouse events.

Without much experience with cocoa, I’ve tried some methods with no success:

- went through the [Technical Note 2128 via internet archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20090112100224/http://developer.apple.com/technotes/tn2005/tn2128.html#TNTAG12), which gave me the suitable explanations of plist items. Still, nothing about keyup.
- tried adding NSKeyUpMask to `recognizedEvents:` in [IMKStateSetting Protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/IMKStateSetting_Protocol/Reference/IMKStateSetting_Ref.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006159-CH3-DontLinkElementID_2), but that didn’t seem to catch the event either.
- tested a bit with [addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:handler:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSEvent_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSEvent/addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask%3ahandler%3a)  but nothing happens.
- failed to find a way to make `NSFlagsChanged` event fire with spacebar.
- read about [Quartz Event Service](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/Reference/reference.html) and `CGEventTap` which seems to handle user inputs in lower level. Didn’t go further to this route, yet.
- [IOHIDManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IOKit/Reference/IOHIDManager_header_reference/Reference/reference.html)?

I reached to a conclusion that IMKit is only capable of passively receiving events.
Since it is not an application, there is no `keyUp:` method to override - AFAIK, IMKit does not inherit `NSResponder` class.

Unfortunately cocoa is way too broad and has much less (or overflowed with non-helping) documentations for a novice like me to dive in.

Can anyone help me to the right direction?

Comment: Very disappointing to learn that Input Method Kit doesn't catch `NSKeyDown` events. Makes a whole class of chorded input methods impossible. If possible, please duplicate rdar://21376535 requesting these additional events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried all possible alternatives one by one, and eventually achieved it by creating a global EventTap 
with `CGEventTap`.

The code basically looks like this:

```objc
// Create an event tap.
CGEventMask eventMask = ((1 << kCGEventKeyDown) | (1 << kCGEventKeyUp));
CFMachPortRef eventTap = CGEventTapCreate(kCGSessionEventTap,
                            kCGHeadInsertEventTap,
                            0,
                            eventMask,
                            myCGEventCallback,
                            NULL);

if (!eventTap) {
    NSLog(@"failed to create event tap\n");
    return NO;
} else {
    // Create a run loop source.
    runLoopSource = CFMachPortCreateRunLoopSource(kCFAllocatorDefault, eventTap, 0);
    // Add to the current run loop.
    CFRunLoopAddSource(CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), runLoopSource, kCFRunLoopCommonModes);
    // Enable the event tap.
    CGEventTapEnable(eventTap, true);
    return YES;
}
```

where `myCGEventCallback` handles the global states.

Meanwhile here are some of what I've found out:

- According to [The Key-Input Message Sequence](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/TextFonts/Conceptual/CocoaTextArchitecture/TextEditing/TextEditing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009459-CH3-SW30) document, the application only passes the keydown event to the Input Method Kit, after trying other bunch of handlers in the chain. You cannot let `IMKServerInput` 'catch' the NSKeyUp event. Just adding an `NSKeyUpMask` to `recognizedEvents:` would not work.
- `addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:handler:` and `CGEventTapCreateForPSN` would not catch the event. I suppose this is because though an Input Method may run as a separate process, the event itself is fired from the application, like TextEdit, and handed over to the Input `Method.
- `IOHIDManager:` is for adding new hardware devices and making drivers.
- Creating a global EventTap requires either running the process with sudo privilege -- copying the Input Method to `/Library/Input Methods` does not run with sudo privilege --, or registering the application to the Accessibility control. That's in System Preferences → Security & Privacy →  Privacy tab → Accessibility, in Mavericks.

Answer (score 0):

`IMKStateSetting` protocol's `recognizedEvents:` method *should* enable `NSKeyUp` events:

```
- (NSUInteger)recognizedEvents:(id)sender {
    return NSKeyDownMask | NSKeyUpMask;
}
```

> A client calls this method to check whether an input method supports an event. The default implementation returns NSKeyDownMask.

However, in testing my Input Method still does not catch `NSKeyUp` events. This seems like a bug.

I've filed the following Radar, and hope others will duplicate it:

rdar://21376535